# Are there any algorithms where a bi-directional map is useful?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you have a map `m`. The bi-directional map would have the following three properties:

1. If only one key, `k` maps to a single value `v` , then
   `m[k] = v`, and `m[v] = k`
2. If `k` maps to an array of values, then
   `m[k] = [v1, v2, ...]`, and `m[v1] = k, m[v2] = k, ...`
3. If multiple `k` map to a single value `v` , then
   `m[k1] = v, m[k2] = v, ...` and `m[v] = [k1, k2, ...]`

Algorithms that use something similar to this, but not exactly this are welcome as well.

Comment: an adjacency list in an undirected graph can make use of such a structure because every node acts both as key and as value. So basically all graph traversal/manipulation algorithms which use an adjacency list are relevant to your case.

Comment: Any lookup table where you need both: 1. the value(s) for a key. 2. the key(s) for a value. Some examples: user id and a username or email address, an object and similar/related objects (this would be a graph), tasks and assignees, useful to cache things like this instead of asking a web service everytime,...